# Scala Play application integration tests with guice context

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, integration-testing, guice

I'm new to play framework and have limited experience with scala. Using `play framework 2.4` I'm trying to write full integrations tests where I want to call controller, and using in-memory db retrieve data from it. I'm using `scalatest-plus` together with `scalatest`. I have read about play unit tests in play documentation and now trying to use `play.api.test.FakeApplication` but i cannot find a way to inject my guice module to this fake application. I'm ussing `OneAppPerSuite` trait I can override `FakeApplication` but cannot pass any `guice` module for injection. Here is `FakeApplication` source from:

```
case class FakeApplication(
  override val path: java.io.File = new java.io.File("."),
  override val classloader: ClassLoader = classOf[FakeApplication].getClassLoader,
  additionalPlugins: Seq[String] = Nil,
  withoutPlugins: Seq[String] = Nil,
  additionalConfiguration: Map[String, _ <: Any] = Map.empty,
  withGlobal: Option[play.api.GlobalSettings] = None,
  withRoutes: PartialFunction[(String, String), Handler] = PartialFunction.empty) extends Application {

private val app: Application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .in(Environment(path, classloader, Mode.Test))
  .global(withGlobal.orNull)
  .configure(additionalConfiguration)
  .bindings(
    bind[FakePluginsConfig] to FakePluginsConfig(additionalPlugins, withoutPlugins),
    bind[FakeRouterConfig] to FakeRouterConfig(withRoutes))
  .overrides(
    bind[Plugins].toProvider[FakePluginsProvider],
    bind[Router].toProvider[FakeRouterProvider])
  .build

  ....
```

So there is no way for me to pass custom module here.

Here is how my test looks like:

```scala
class UsersControllerTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

    override implicit lazy val app = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())

    "Application " should {

       "work" in {
         val resp = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/api/users")).get
        }
    }
```

}

And here is my controller I want to test:

```
class UserController @Inject()
  (userService: UserService)
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

  def get = Action.async { implicit request => {
    // implementation
    }
  }
```

}

Obviously my test now fail since it cannot find `UserService` instance.
So my question is:

1. How to properly write end2end integration tests with play using guice context
2. Is it common to write such tests in play application, since I cannot find any decent examples or documentation of doing something like that. I used to write such tests in java web applications where integration tests load spring context, but can't find such examples in play.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to test your default configuration, starting FakeApplication, is enough. It loads modules specified in `application.conf` automatically. So, If it can't find `UserService`, that means you don't have proper module configurations in your `application.conf` and there for your server can't serve those requests.

   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection
2. If you want to use some Mockups, and override default configurations:

   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice